# HM Prison & Probation Service Overpayment

Tags: salary

My son has recieved a letter today requesting him pay £7756.13 in overpayments that have occured as a result of basic pay. He left the service last year Jan 2022 . This has come as a complete shock to him. They have sent a break down but it is impossible to understand and he is convinced he hasnt been overpaid. What should he do as this will push him into extreme hardship with all his other bills and maintence he pays for his children.

Comment: Contacting [Citizens Advice](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/) would probably be a good idea. I don't think that this question is on-topic here as a "Workplace" question.

Answer (score 1):

If they have overpaid him then they can ask for the money back, however if the overpayments were a long time ago (sounds like the case here) and/or over a significant period of time (again, sounds like the case here) then they have to be "fair and flexible" in how repayment is handled. Including potentially coming to an arrangement for a payment plan.

With this in mind it's wise to engage with them in the process - otherwise they may choose to pursue the debt in court.

This of course assumes that they *have* overpaid him, which is by no means a given. Have him dig out as much paperwork relating to that job and in particular pay as he can find. Payslips (both for the alleged overpayment periods and "normal") and look for differences. Any documentation that discusses salary - original contract, any letters regarding raises etc.

If your son and his former employer cannot reach agreement - either on a payment plan or even on whether the overpayment is real your son should contact the [ACAS Helpline](https://www.acas.org.uk/contact) .

Answer (score 0):

> What should he do as this will push him into extreme hardship with all
> his other bills and maintence he pays for his children.

He should pay what he owes.

If he is convinced that he doesn't owe anything, he should get legal help to contest the charges.

Otherwise, he should attempt to negotiate a payment schedule to try to make the repayment as painless as possible.